# Is there any way to skip a value in a vuetify's data table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This is my vuetify's data table

```
 <v-data-table
            :headers="headersRemittances"
            :items="remittances"
            :loading="loadingRemittances"
            class="elevation-2 col-12 pa-0"
            item-key="index"
            sortBy="identifier"
            update: sort-desc
            hide-default-footer
            disable-pagination
          >
```

I have been trying to "skip" some particular elements of that array (because they have a repeated ID, but erasing them its not an option), maybe with a conditional, but i dont know if it is possible.

EDIT:

Found a way using a some() property and filtering the data into a new array as follows:

```
      filterRemittances () {
  this.filteredRemittances = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.remittances.length; i++) {
    if (this.filteredRemittances.length == 0) {
    this.filteredRemittances.push(this.remittances[i])
    }
    if (this.filteredRemittances.some(val => val.id != this.remittances[i].id)) {
    this.filteredRemittances.push(this.remittances[i])
    }
  }
}
```

After that i replace the new filteredRemittance array in my v-data-table

```
          <v-data-table
        :headers="headersRemittances"
        :items="filteredRemittances"
        :loading="loadingRemittances"
        class="elevation-2 col-12 pa-0"
        item-key="index"
        sortBy="identifier"
        update: sort-desc
        hide-default-footer
        disable-pagination
      >
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend modifying this.filterRemittances inside the filterRemittances computed (modifying itself). It'd be safer to create a `const temp = []` instead, then `return temp` at the end in the computed

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a computed to filter out the items you don't need, then plug the new filtered table into the "items" prop

```html
<template>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headersRemittances"
            :items="formattedRemittances"
            :loading="loadingRemittances"
            class="elevation-2 col-12 pa-0"
            item-key="index"
            sortBy="identifier"
            update: sort-desc
            hide-default-footer
            disable-pagination
          />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ....
  computed: {
    formattedRemittances() {
      return this.remmitances.filter(remmitance => remmitance.amount < 200);
    }  
  }
}
</script>
```

The value of formattedRemittances will automatically update whenever `this.remmitances` changes

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I might use this one for another case.